# How to call named XSLT template from java

Tags: java, xslt

I have `XSLT` file with named templates:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template name="A">...</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="B">...</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="C">...</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I call named templates `(A,B,C)` from java code (I need this just for testing)?

Comment: As temporally solution I can propose [programmatically create xslt file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501566/create-xslt-files-programmatically) that will call required template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XSLT 1.0` doesn't allow this. `XSLT 2.0` does, but the API depends on the product you are using (`JAXP` never caught up with `XSLT 2.0`). For `Saxon`, use the `s9api` method `XsltTransformer.setInitialTemplate()`.