# How to generate an XSLT programatically

Tags: xslt, saxon

I am trying to use Saxon to programmatically generate an XSLT.  This is a similar question to  [Create xslt files programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501566/create-xslt-files-programmatically), but as there was no acceptable answer to that question I am asking again, specifically around Saxon which at one point claimed to support this.

According to http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon7.0/api-guide.html, "This document describes how to use Saxon as a Java class library, without making any use of XSLT stylesheets."

(answering the other question I referred to above) and then serialize that to a stylesheet that could then be reloaded and executed later, but I already pretty much figured out that isn't going to happen.

If Saxon isn't the answer, what Java library will support any of this?

By the way, doing any and all of this using .Net is trivial.  Unfortunately I need a Java solution for this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: XSLT is XML. So generating XSLT requires the same process as generating XML. (Also, if you have a working .NET version of what you want to do, please show it. Without a proper specification this question is too broad.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, for a start, there have been 26 major releases and innumerable maintenance releases of Saxon since release 7.0, so forget anything you read there.

It's not clear from your question whether you want to write your XSLT code generator in Java or in XSLT. I can't see why you would want to do it in Java rather than XSLT, but neither is difficult. The main problem with your question is that you don't explain why you think it's a problem. Generating an XSLT stylesheet is just like generating any other XML document: what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out a while ago, and thought I would share my answer.  This may or may be an answer for [Create xslt files programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501566/create-xslt-files-programmatically) as well, but since that was not my question, I won't assume that.

The answer is not to use XSLT (or Saxon) at all.  Originally I wanted an API with which to generate an XSLT model where the rules for transforming a particular (xml) tree structure are known programmatically. Then the model could be persisted as a style sheet so that it could be reloaded and used to transform another tree with the same structure again.  Sure I could programmatically create a DOM containing an XSLT style sheet document, but why would I want to?  It's inefficient for one - creating and saving a DOM with all the XSLT syntax (tedious), and then reading it using SAXON, etc.  I'd rather have an API that natively understands XSLT - maybe one that has an XSLT model that can just be programmed and then serialized?

Anyway, the answer to my problem is just to use SAX.  Since I know the particular transformation rules for my tree programmatically, I simply created a handler that processes the stream using the rules, and I'm done.  In the end there's no XSLT style sheet that can live outside the program, but I'll live with that.

And I take back what I said about .Net supporting my first approach.  I thought it would so it's just a reminder to check your assumptions before you post.

By the way, an answer to my question suggested that it was easy to accomplish but rather than outline how to do it, I was just questioned why I would want to.  Can we at least try to answer a question if we also feel we need to ask someone why they are asking a question?

Comment: "*Can we at least try to answer a question if we also feel we need to ask someone why they are asking a question?*" I often ask people  why they are asking a question, so that I can figure out what answer might be helpful to them.

Comment: Michael, my question was whether Saxon could be used to generate XSLT programmatically.  In reply I was told it is easy but without any details.  I was also told XSLT is just XML and to generate it like any other XML (again without details - but presumably via DOM, which wouldn't involve Saxon.  So the answer to my question should be no I guess).  If Saxon can be used to generate XSLT then details would be nice.  As far as the problem I am solving I described it in my own answer.  I know the structure to be transformed programmatically and want a simple programmatic way to transform it.

Comment: I don't think this is a good place to have this discussion. I was merely commenting on why it is often necessary to understand where the person asking the question is coming from.

Comment: I will tell you this in a nutshell: XSLT **transforms** XML documents. If you have an XML input that you want to turn into an XSLT stylesheet, in some predefined way, then you can write an XSLT stylesheet to describe the transformation, and have any XSLT engine (such as Saxon) execute the transformation, producing the required XSLT stylesheet, to be used (presumably) in another transformation, using another XML input, to produce another output. No additional details can be given intelligently without additional details being provided first.