# Generating XSL stylesheet in java (xml to xml)

Tags: java, xml, xslt

i need a java code which makes an xsl style sheet that transforms an xml file to another xml file. but it should be dynamic.

i want to set the xsl:element names and path. and the java code should generate 
me automaticly.

i have made one but if i want to change my type of xml, i need to add like 30 line code.

example from my code;

```
string xslelementstart = "<xsl:element name=\"" ;
string elementend="</xsl:element>";
string value="<xsl:value-of select=\"";
string name = "";(will be public and can be changed)
string path = "";(will be public and can be changed)
string end="\"\>";
string end2="\">";

if(path!="")
{ 
 string xsl = xslelementstart+name+end2+"\n"+
              value+path+end+"\n"
              elementend
}
```

this is an example of my java code not the actual. im working with a big xml file. i want other xml files to be in my xml file format.but if i want to change my xml file (like adding another element) this code is not useful.as i said i should only set the values of my xml file and the java code should generates me. is it possible?

Comment: Rather than build up an XSLT in this way, bear in mind an XSLT is a well-formed XML document, and so can actually be used as input to another XSLT. So, have one XSLT which is a basic "template" which is then used as the input of a second XSLT which transforms it by adding the `xsl:element` and `xsl:value-of` you need (also using parameters passed into the second XSLT).

Comment: thank you for your advice. i will try

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation is ugly, use Document Builder.
See the similar question: [Create xslt files programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501566/create-xslt-files-programmatically)